# How to add box shadow in specific area using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to create box shadow using CSS but in a specific area of the box only.

[image]
As shown in the screenshot above, I have blue header on a site and to that header, I want to add a shadow in a specific position as highlighted with red box.

I am guessing that using psuedo element :after on header div should work but I don't know how to add shadow with specific styling. I mean if you notice, the shadow is blurred on left and right.

Comment: Add snippet or jsFiddle for see what you have tried so far please

Comment: you can use a pseudo element to produce the shadow. It is actually a classic method . Is there any code you tryed that shows your issue that could be used to point at your failures and usable to show a working example ?

Comment: _“the shadow is blurred on left and right”_ – in that case you’re better off not using box-shadow in the first place; but a background gradient that fades into transparent on the sides.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer some css shadow generator website like http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow  to make shadow to particular area.Hope this may helps you.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 1px; 
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-1px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```